# What do I use as the database path?

Tags: java, database, neo4j

I have been searching through documentation on how to create nodes and the only example I find uses this approach

```
graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
```

What am I suppose to use for DB_PATH? The following link describes it as the data store directory http://api.neo4j.org/1.4/org/neo4j/kernel/EmbeddedGraphDatabase.html I've tried using "data/graph.db" given that is an actually directory holding what appears to be data files but that is still me just guessing.

**Note**:

I'm using Neo4j - 2.0.0-M03 the Java api

Comment: That is just the location that you want your database to be. If you want to use and existing database then you would make it where those files reside. Otherwise just make it a new directory.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly there is no expected path? What ever I place as DB_PATH is where data will be stored. So this does not need to match some configuration option?

Comment: One more question. Is it suppose to be an absolute path or relative? The reason I ask is that I have an error being thrown by that line of code only at run time.(java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException)

Comment: can you give an sscce along with the stack trace.

Comment: a relative path is fine. I cannot replicate your issue. If you are using an IDE try shutting it down and restarting.

Comment: I ended up solving it by creating the path manually ahead of time and using the full path. Perhaps it was something to do with my local permissions.

Answer (score 2):

**DB_PATH** is simply where you want the database to be stored on disk. What ever you set it to should match the following field

`org.neo4j.server.database.location`

inside the file

`/conf/neo4j-server.properties`

Having those two match will allow the WebAdmin application to find the correct DB. The WebAdmin application can be accessed at `http://127.0.0.1:7474/webadmin`